# Pandas dataframe parse string column to extract dates into new column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe containing a string column:

> ```
> text = ['dasndljaksdhfinwejfiv 12/05/2018'', 'akdhaouiyfbh adv12.03.2019','faytdvi advonalsdnfoaidv 5/9/2019IUAYFNVVKNVAIUEHF']
> ```

I want to extract just the dates from this and add to a new column.

I have tried the following but it just returns the original string value of the column:

```
df['date'] = df.text.replace({r"\d{2}[\/ ](\d{2}|January|Jan)[\/ ]\d{2,4}"},regex=True)
```

What's the best way to get around this?

Comment: You probably wanted `df['date'] = df['text'].str.extract(r"(\d{2}[/. ](?:\d{2}|January|Jan)[/. ]\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)")`

Comment: I added a more appropriate pattern below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `.str.extract()`, use `\d{1,2}` to match 1-digit days and months and add the `.` to the delimiters pattern:

```
df['date'] = df['text'].str.extract(r"(\d{1,2}[/. ](?:\d{1,2}|January|Jan)[/. ]\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)")
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kTNSbl/1).

Also, note that `\d{2}(?:\d{2})?` matches 2 or 4 digits, and `\d{2,4}` matches 2, 3 or 4 digits.

Note that the whole regex pattern is wrapped with a capturing group, it is necessary because `.str.extract` requires at least one capturing group to work, it will yield just the text captured.

To match the dates not inside other digits, you may add `(?<!\d)` at the start and `(?!\d)` at the end, it may make the pattern safer.

If you plan to match any English month name you need to expand the pattern a little:

```
r"(?<!\d)(\d{1,2}[/. ](?:\d{1,2}|(?:J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ne?|ly?))|Feb(?:ruary)?|Ma(?:r(?:ch)?|y)|A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Sep(?:t(?:ember)?)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?))[/. ]\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)(?!\d)"
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kTNSbl/2).

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately to the left is allowed
- `(` - start of a capturing group
- `\d{1,2}`  - 1 or 2 digits
- `[/. ]` - space, `/` or `.`
- `(?:\d{1,2}|(?:J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ne?|ly?))|Feb(?:ruary)?|Ma(?:r(?:ch)?|y)|A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Sep(?:t(?:ember)?)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?))` - month name, abbreviated or not
- `[/. ]` - space, `/` or `.`
- `\d{2}(?:\d{2})?` - 2 digits followed with an optional sequence of two digits
- `)` - end of the capturing group
- `(?!\d)` - no digit immediately to the right is allowed

Comment: How would this be modified to allow for 2 digit dates within the text as well? Such as 02/13, 2/13 etc

Comment: @user10 Add an optional group, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/kTNSbl/3), `(?<!\d)(\d{1,2}[/. ](?:(?:\d{1,2}|(?:J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ne?|ly?))|Feb(?:ruary)?|Ma(?:r(?:ch)?|y)|A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Sep(?:t(?:ember)?)?|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?))[/. ])?\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)(?!\d)`